# ReactJS: Join map output with concatenating value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, output

In my ReactJS application I am getting the mobile numbers as a string which I need to break and generate a link for them to be clickable on the mobile devices. But, instead I am getting `[object Object], [object Object]` as an output, whereas it should be `xxxxx, xxxxx, ...`.

Also, I need to move this `mobileNumbers` function to a separate location where it can be accessed via multiple components.
*For example:* Currently this code is located in the `Footer` component and this code is also need on the `Contact Us` component.

```
...
function isEmpty(value) {
    return ((value === undefined) || (value === null))
        ? ''
        : value;
};

function mobileNumbers(value) {
    const returning = [];

    if(isEmpty(value))
    {
        var data = value.split(',');

        data.map((number, index) => {
            var trimed = number.trim();

            returning.push(<NavLink to={`tel:${trimed}`} key={index}>{trimed}</NavLink>);
        });

        return returning.join(', ');
    }

    return '';
};
...
```

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is there any way to create a separate file for the common constants / functions like this to be accessed when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**

> What am I doing wrong here?

The issue what you have is happening because of [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). If creates a string at the end of the day. From the documentation:

> The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string. If the array has only one item, then that item will be returned without using the separator.

Think about the following:

```js
const navLinks = [{link:'randomlink'}, {link:'randomlink2'}];
console.log(navLinks.join(','))
```

If you would like to use concatenate with `,` then you can do similarly like this:

```
function mobileNumbers(value) {
    if(isEmpty(value)) {
        const data = value.split(',');

        return data.map((number, index) => {
            const trimed = number.trim();
            return <NavLink to={`tel:${trimed}`} key={index}>{trimed}</NavLink>;
        }).reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr]);
    }

    return [];
};
```

Then you need to use `map()` in JSX to make it work.

**Second question:**

> Is there any way to create a separate file for the common constants / functions like this to be accessed when needed?

Usually what I do for constants is that I create in the `src` folder a file called `Consts.js` and put there as the following:

```
export default {
    AppLogo: 'assets/logo_large.jpg',
    AppTitle: 'Some app name',
    RunFunction: function() { console.log(`I'm running`) }
}
```

Then simply `import` in a component when something is needed like:

```
import Consts from './Consts';
```

And using in `render` for example:

```
return <>
   <h1>{Consts.AppTitle}</h1>
</>
```

Similarly you can call functions as well.

**+1 suggestion:**

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array so you don't need to create one as you did earlier. From the documentation:

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @norbitrial, it worked. Happy New Year... :)

Comment: @Pummi Awesome, Happy New Year to you too!

Comment: @Pummi Just extended my answer with the second question's explanation. I hope that clarifies.